# Misunderstanding about continuous functions over open and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, continuity

How do these two propositions sit together?

1. Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a continuous function
   and let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$ be an open set, so $f^{-1}(A)$
   is an open set.
2. Every open set $\mathbb{A\subseteq R}^{m}$ is a continuous image
   of a closed set.

I guess i'm just missing something here, but as i see it, the 2nd states
that for every open set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$ exists a closed
set $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$
such that $f(C)=A$.

But that gives us that $C=f^{-1}(A)$ which contradicts
the 1st no?

Answer (score 1):

From $f(C)=A$ you only get $f^{-1}(f(C))=f^{-1}(A)$. It is quite possible that $f^{-1}(f(C))\supsetneq C$.

Comment: and what if we only look at the restricted function $\left.f\right|_{C}$?

Comment: If you look at restricted functions, 2. becomes easy anyway: start with an open set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, take $C=A$  and $f:C\to\mathbb{R}^m$ the identity on $C$. Equip $C$ with the subspace topology. In the subspace topology, $C$ is closed. Its image $A$ is still open in $\mathbb{R}^m$.